# restart systemd-networkd .link files without reboot

Tags: networking, systemd, systemctl

I have a `eth0.link` file to change MAC address of interface eth0. I want to apply this change without reboot. I tried

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl daemon-reexec 
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Is any other to restart .link file.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
systemctl restart systemd-udev-trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

systemctl restart network.service

systemctl force-reload systemd-networkd.service